# PHP Regular expression parsing

Tags: php

I am having an array of strings.

```
(102) Name3
```

How can I match for strings starting with (####) and get the Name part of the line easily.
I am trying the following which is not working.

```
if(preg_match("/(d+)/", $myArray[$i], $matches))
```

Comment: can you show me your complete code and desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the parentheses that are in the expected input string:

```
if(preg_match("/\((\d+)\) (.+)$/", $myArray[$i], $matches))
```

That's the following regular expression:

- `/` Start of regex (this can be any character, but is usually a /)
- `\(` the character (
- `(` begin capturing group 1
- `\d` any digit
- `+` previous match, 1 or more times
- `)` end capturing group 1
- a space
- `(` begin capturing group 2
- `.` almost any character
- `+` previous match, 1 or more times
- `)` end capturing group 2
- `$` end of string
- `/` End of regex (must match first character)

You can find more descriptive definitions on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

With the above, matches will contain for example:

```
array(
    '(123) input string',
    123, // capturing group 1
    'input string' // capturing group 2
)
```

Comment: can u pls let me know what is (.+)?